# how to ignore extra key in json and get value

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to use a common code to read JSON objects that have different structures but has the same "parent" key/property. I just need to be able to get the value in the end.

Example:

```
var ObjA = { "StartDate": "2016" }
var ObjB = { "StartDate": { "S": "2016" } }
```

I know that I am able to get the value from ObjB using `StartDate.S` but I was wondering if there is any way to bypass the `S` and just use `StartDate` to get the `2016` value.

So if I were to get the value from both objects, I just need to use `StartDate`.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `parsedJson.StartDate.s || parsedJson.StartDate`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with checking if `S` parameter exists - if not - just treat `StartDate` as a result:

```
var result = obj.StartDate.S || obj.StartDate;
```